# Why is it that my MacBook Pro Retina's resolution is detected as different based on the application?

Tags: macbook-pro, java, resolution, display

The actual advertized resolution is 2880 x 1800.
Taking a fullscreen, screenshot gives me an image that is 2880 x 1800.
Going to [this site](http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/) tells me my resolution is 1440 x 900.
The built in Digital Color Meter tells me my resolution is 1440 x 900.
This bit of Java code:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();
System.out.println(width + " x " + height);
```

has an output of 1440 x 900.

So why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Which site is that - a link without explaination is not something anyone should click on. Also which version of Java?

Comment: Sorry about that. The site is http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/ which just displays your screen resolution. I'm using Java 8 Update 45.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am an iOS developer, so have a bit of an idea what is causing this.  Apple measure screen size in *points* rather than *pixels*, and depending on whether your screen is a retina display or not, will change the scaling factor between *points* and physical pixels.

In your case, because you have a high-resolution Retina display, OS X is applying a scale factor of 2.0.  This means that a webpage that has been designed with an element 500px across will still appear the right physical size (however it will in fact be 1000px across).

It's not a bug, it's a feature that means the retina display can still show the "old-fashioned" normal resolution content.